# What is the equivalent PHP code of rowCount using ODBC?

Tags: php, odbc, rowcount

Using PDO I use `rowCount()`.

What is equivalent code for `rowCount()` using ODBC in PHP?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`odbc_num_rows()` maybe?

Google found [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-num-rows.php)